# r.recode rules file issue

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis

I have a raster that I want to reclassify and I'm using GRASS r.recode from within QGIS v.2.4.0. The rules file I am using has this content:

```
0:149:1
150:229:2
230:379:3
380:459:4
460:*:5
```

The raster I have has a maximum value of 515 and according to the rules file, it should be reclassified as 5 but the range in the output raster from r.recode is [1,4].

Any ideas as to what is wrong with my rules file?

Comment: IF you want to reclassify, then consider r.reclass instead of r.recode: http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.reclass.html

Comment: I also tried using r.reclass with the following rules file but got the same result: the range of the output raster is [1,4].`0 thru 149 = 1
150 thru 229 = 2
230 thru 379 = 3
380 thru 459 = 4
* = 5`

Comment: Please edit your posting to better show the content of the r.reclass file. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had not loaded the min / max values in the raster layer's style properties.

Comment: Is this an answer or comment?

Comment: It's an answer.